# GStreamer: Input from osxaudiosrc with more than 8 channels

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to receive audio from an OSX audio device with 64 input channels (Soundflower64 in this example) and record them to a multichannel wav.

I get the first 8 channels without problems with this basic command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 osxaudiosrc device=78 ! wavenc ! filesink location=audio.wav
```

But I found no way to widen this pipeline to 64 channels. Nothing seems to work...

Can it be done or is this an inherent limitation of GStreamer?

Answer (score 1):

This still looks like a hardcoded limit in GStreamer - https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/972184f434c3212aa313eacb9025869d050e91c3/sys/osxaudio/gstosxcoreaudio.h#L67

**Edit**: I made a pull request to Gstreamer to increase this to 64, which has now been released in v1.20. See https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/1.20/subprojects/gst-plugins-good/sys/osxaudio/gstosxcoreaudio.h#L66